Calculation problems in PHP Laravel
I'm developing a room registration and reservation system in Laravel and I'm having trouble updating a room's information when I add products in the Register_update function.
Context:
The room price is stored in the database and is fixed, but is dynamically adjusted in the system to calculate the cost based on the hours or days of the stay.
Additionally, products consumed in the room (such as drinks or snacks) are added and must be added to the final bill total.
The problem arises when I add a product in the Register_update function. Instead of correctly adding up to the total, the price of the product appears to incorrectly add or modify the value of the room.
            foreach($detalle_first as $product) {
                if ($product['impuesto'] == 1) {
                    $igv_first        +=  number_format((((float) $product['precio_unitario'] - (float) $product['precio_unitario'] / 1.18) * (int) $product['cantidad']), 2, ".", "");
                    $igv_first        = $this->redondeado($igv_first);
                }
    
                if ($product["codigo_igv"] == "10") {
                    $gravada_first    += number_format((((float) $product['precio_unitario'] / 1.18) * (int) $product['cantidad']), 2, ".", "");
                    $gravada_first     = $this->redondeado($gravada_first);
                }
    
                if ($product["codigo_igv"] == "20") {
                    $exonerada_first   += number_format(((float) $product['precio_unitario'] * (int) $product['cantidad']), 2, ".", "");
                    $exonerada_first   = $this->redondeado($exonerada_first);
                }
    
                if ($product["codigo_igv"] == "30") {
                    $inafecta_first    += number_format(((float) $product['precio_unitario'] * (int) $product['cantidad']), 2, ".", "");
                    $inafecta_first     = str_replace(',', '', $inafecta_first);
                    $inafecta_first     = $this->redondeado($inafecta_first);
                }
                $subtotal_first   = $exonerada_first + $gravada_first + $inafecta_first;
            }
    
            if(!empty($detalle_last)) {
                foreach($detalle_last as $product) {
                    if ($product['impuesto'] == 1) {
                        $igv_last        +=  number_format((((float) $product['precio_unitario'] - (float) $product['precio_unitario'] / 1.18) * (int) $product['cantidad']), 2, ".", "");
                        $igv_last        = $this->redondeado($igv_last);
                    }
        
                    if ($product["codigo_igv"] == "10") {
                        $gravada_last    += number_format((((float) $product['precio_unitario'] / 1.18) * (int) $product['cantidad']), 2, ".", "");
                        $gravada_last     = $this->redondeado($gravada_last);
                    }
        
                    if ($product["codigo_igv"] == "20") {
                        $exonerada_last   += number_format(((float) $product['precio_unitario'] * (int) $product['cantidad']), 2, ".", "");
                        $exonerada_last   = $this->redondeado($exonerada_last);
                    }
        
                    if ($product["codigo_igv"] == "30") {
                        $inafecta_last    += number_format(((float) $product['precio_unitario'] * (int) $product['cantidad']), 2, ".", "");
                        $inafecta_last     = str_replace(',', '', $inafecta_last);
                        $inafecta_last     = $this->redondeado($inafecta_last);
                    }
                    $subtotal_last   = $exonerada_last + $gravada_last + $inafecta_last;
                }
            }
    
            Reception::where('id', $idrecepcion)->update([
                'fecha_salida'  => $fecha_salida,
                'exonerada'     => $exonerada_first + $exonerada_last,
                'inafecta'      => $inafecta_first + $inafecta_last,
                'gravada'       => $gravada_first + $gravada_last,
                'anticipo'      => "0.00",
                'igv'           => $igv_first + $igv_last,
                'gratuita'      => "0.00",
                'otros_cargos'  => "0.00",
                'total'         => $subtotal_first + $subtotal_last,
                'observaciones' => mb_strtoupper($observaciones),
            ]);

That when adding product does not add to the cost of the room.

This is the likely problem:
number_format((((float) $product['precio_unitario'] - (float) $product['precio_unitario'] / 1.18) * (int) $product['cantidad']), 2, ".", "")

You subtract (float) $product['precio_unitario'] / 1.18 from (float) $product['precio_unitario']. You would likely only need to compute the product of precio_unitario and cantidad and add the result to the variable that you have. You have this strange (probably mistaken) pattern for $igv_first, $gravada_first, $exonerada_first and $inafecta_first alike. Also, it is unclear how you initialize them and what exactly redondeado is.
